# In the area of effect of Sleet Storm, do creatures gain the Blinded condition?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, conditions

If a creature is inside a [Sleet Storm](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/sleetStorm.html) spell, does it gain the [Blinded condition](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/glossary.html#blinded)? For example, does it take the -2 penalty to Armor Class from Blinded?

The relevant text of Sleet Storm:

> Driving sleet blocks all sight (even darkvision) within it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## No.

The spell would state that the creatures would become blinded if that were the case.

For example:

[Blindness/Deafness](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/blindnessDeafness.html#blindness-deafness)

> You call upon the powers of unlife to render the subject **blinded** or deafened, as you choose.

You can see above, the spell specifically states the victim is blinded.

---

[Sleet Storm](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/sleetStorm.html)

> Driving sleet blocks all sight (even darkvision) within it and causes the ground in the area to be icy. A creature can walk within or through the area of sleet at half normal speed with a DC 10 Acrobatics check. Failure means it can't move in that round, while failure by 5 or more means it falls (see the Acrobatics skill for details).

You can see above they are effectively blinded, but it doesn't state they are literally.

---

[Blinded](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Blinded) Condition

> The creature cannot see. It takes a –2 penalty to Armor Class, loses its Dexterity bonus to AC (if any), and takes a –4 penalty on most Strength- and Dexterity-based skill checks and on opposed Perception skill checks. All checks and activities that rely on vision (such as reading and Perception checks based on sight) automatically fail. All opponents are considered to have total concealment (50% miss chance) against the blinded character. Blind creatures must make a DC 10 Acrobatics skill check to move faster than half speed. Creatures that fail this check fall prone. Characters who remain blinded for a long time grow accustomed to these drawbacks and can overcome some of them.

Conditions, such as blindness above, are specific and in this case do more to the victim than what the spell states.

Answer (score 3):

## No, but

But there is no need for it, really.

### [Total Concealment](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Total-Concealment)

This condition still applies, in both directions. You have no line of sight to each other.

### Acrobatics to move

DC 10 Acrobatics skill check to move is granted both by the blinded condition and the spell.

### Other penalties are less important, and looks like meant that way

True, -2 to AC is bad, but with 50% miss chance already does it matter that much? And given the fact this spell carefully not used blinded condition, it was probably meant that way. After all, you can see as far as 3 feet in real sleet, so it seems reasonable to assume character can see the sword coming, or even an arrow flying his way. At least when they are really close.